# Is it possible to use a NAS to host videos?

Tags: nas, storage, cloud

Is it possible to use a NAS, in which I put videos, to watch what I would like to be able to watch at any time, for me and my friends?

However I'm not good at programming at all, so I wanted to know if it was possible to use a ready-made hosting site, which would allow me to play the huge amount of videos I'll have on it, and also allow my friends to do so via a simple URL.

3 or 4 years ago I had seen someone doing it. It was a very green site on which you had to have an account, and which took you directly to the catalog of videos that the person had put via his NAS.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What research have you done? Plex is a decent tool for this sort of thing, and has been a long time. Some NAS devices support it out of the box.

Comment: If you have a good upload speed and a moderately fast CPU then look into PLEX.

Comment: Depending on your use-case, you may want realtime encoding so you can stream to devices (chromecast, firestick, mobile, etc.) that work better with a certain bitrate/resolution/framerate etc.  That's not classically something a NAS is good at.

Comment: "Is it possible...?" would seem to be answered by "3 or 4 years ago I had seen someone doing it."  What kind of answer(s) are you looking for here?  A simple Yes/No, software recommendations, or a blueprint to implement this yourself?  Any of those seem problematic as far as this being a useful, focused, on-topic question.

Comment: For a few years now I've had a Sandisk thumbdrive with a built-in wifi server that allows 3 simultaneous users.  I would hope there are more sophisticated devices available.

Answer (score 12):

The rough, practical short answer is "Yes but" .  The long answer is a bit more complex.

A NAS does just what the name implies "Network Attached Storage" - ie its just a store of data.  In reality, most NAS's are built on Linux or BSD and have a lot of add-ons that this empowers.

In the simplest case what you need to achieve this is :

1. A device which stores files and acts as a web server.
2. A means of limiting who can access this.  I would recommend a minimum of a VPN server, possibly with user accounts (you could theoretically get away with user accounts, but this thing is exposed to the Internet)
3. An Internet connection capable of handling large volumes of traffic
4. Videos in a format that can be streamed, and that are compressible.
5. Ideally a web interface that facilitates streaming the video.
6. A routable IP address and appropriate router configuration.  (Sometimes you can run the the VPN on the router rather then the NAS)

Depending on your needs, you may not need to use a web interface.  I've got a much simpler setup - I simply use Windows File Sharing (SAMBA/CIFS/SMB) on my NAS, and have a VPN I connect to home to.  When I want to access media remotely I simply connect to the VPN, instruct VLC with the IP address of the NAS/SMB Server, select the video and watch it.  This works quite practically over my very limited connections - I have a paltry 10 megabit upload from my server and can use my phones 4g connection to stream my video (which is typically 720p - ie 800 megabytes for a 1.5 hour video) to my phone and its quite acceptable for occassional use.

I posit that running Kodi and enabling a web server might be a better way to go, but I've never taken it that far.  Kodi can be installed on some NAS's

Note that none of this will be good enough for more then a small handful of simultaneous users - friends - who you at least somewhat trust to not hack you.

Answer (score 10):

@davidgo's answer is a good starting point and will work basically on anything. But if you've already got that set up and your NAS is a bit beefier (has hardware video encoding support), you can install [Plex](https://www.plex.tv/) on it. It's essentially a personal Netflix. It has a built-in player, runs on anything and can re-encode video on the fly eg. to 720p over poor connections. You can check if it fits your needs in a VM for example.

Comment: [Jellyfin](https://jellyfin.org/) and [Emby](https://emby.media/) can fill the same role as Plex, transcoding included. Personally, I found Emby to be decent and Jellyfin to be even better. Both have apps/clients for many smart TVs and Roku. Jellyfin also has synchronized viewing groups so you can watch simultaneously with friends(web browser only).

Comment: @BoogaRoo Thank you, I remembered there's an alternative but I forgot what it's called (Emby). I'll take a look at Jellyfin too.

Comment: -1: This question is very opinion-based and off-topic. This answer should have been posted as a comment.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I disagree. It's a problem-based question suggesting a software-based solution. [This kind of questions is allowed](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5373/194694) (this link was taken from the "closed as software-rec" banner). It's on topic in the sense of [the first 3 bullet points](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and it's not provoking subjective answers.

Comment: Additionally, if your NAS isn't beefy enough to push videos, it could act as a file share and the Plex Server could be installed on another server (as I do). Sure you can do the same with alternatives.